# Create array from table rows with multiple cell data

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to create a simple array with jquery from a table with only rows, but a row can contain multiple time elements.

I could only find solutions for tables with single td values and no children...

This is my table:

```
<div id="customhours">
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Tuesday</td>
          <td>
            <time>17:00 - 18:00</time>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Friday</td>
          <td>
            <time>16:00 - 17:00</time>
            <time>17:00 - 18:00</time>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

The array I'm looking for is:

```
[["Tuesday", "17:00 - 18:00"], ["Friday", ["16:00 - 17:00, 17:00 - 18:00"]]]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each row, find the day in the first `<td>` and all the `<time>` tags in the last `<td>`:

```js
let a = [] // Results will go here

$('#customhours tr').each(function() {
    let day = $(this).find('td:first-child').text() // e.g. Tuesday
    let times = []
    $(this).find('td:last-child time').each(function(){
        times.push($(this).text())
    })

    a.push([day, ( ( times.length == 1) ? times[0] : times )])
})

console.log(a)
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="customhours">
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Tuesday</td>
          <td>
            <time>17:00 - 18:00</time>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Friday</td>
          <td>
            <time>16:00 - 17:00</time>
            <time>17:00 - 18:00</time>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```